# RestSharp and serializable Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, serialization, restsharp

I have a webApi and an MVC application.
The webApi has all the logic and the MVC application is just the presentation.
Im using RestSharp to get the data from the WebApi to the MVC application.

Im sharing here one method that retrieves all user information

```
  public IUser getUserInformationLogin(string palsoftID)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("FrontDeskLog/GetUserInfo/{PalsoftID}", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddParameter("PalsoftID", palsoftID, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        var response = service.Execute<User>(request);
        return response.Data
    }
```

everything is good until I add Serialize attribute to the User class, I need to make User serializable in order to use session state StateServer for my MVC application. 
But after adding the serialize attr the above method always returns null.
If I debug i can see that in the Response. Content all data is there, but response.data returns a null object.

Any help will be very appreciated.

The Method in the webApi is this one

```
   public IUser GetUserInfo(string PalsoftID)
    {
        FrontDeskDb data = new FrontDeskDb();
        return data.getUsersInfo(PalsoftID);

    }
```

this is the class Roles

```
  public class Roles 
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool Main { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: please post the json (assuming its json) that your webapi is returning along with the class that youre trying to serialize

Comment: Hello @GregH, I have posted the Class, the webApi is just returning the IUser Object im not returning JSON.
I think the deserialization is handled by webapi.